# Keeping 2 instances of Confluence in sync?

Tags: wiki, confluence

We have a lot of traveling users who would like to have their WIKI content (and update it) while not connected to the network. Adding a localhost instance of Confluence is a snap, but how to keep these instances in sync with the main WIKI in the Intranet?
Partial sync (e.g. only current page, no history) or based on a preference is a bonus but not a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/RR/Confluence+RoadRunner

I've never tried it but it seems to be the right plugin

Comment: Looks like the closest I will get. Would be the perfect fit if it was a 1.0 release :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is also Firestarter from Appfire: http://www.appfire.com/products/firestarter/features.jsp
Trying to get a trial for our Wiki organized with them at the moment.